# Parse errors are not displayed

Tags: php, iis-6, error-reporting

I want PHP to display parse errors on screen. What I get instead is a blank page. Nothing gets written to server's error log file.

My setup: PHP5.2.9/**IIS 6** (not Apache!).

My PHP.INI:

```
error_reporting=E_STRICT
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
error_log = "C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\logs\php_error.log"
```

How do I get parse or fatal errors to be either logged or shown on screen?

Thanks,
Temuri

**UPDATE**: After playing with different switches it looks to be an IIS specific problem. ANY IDEAS FOLKS?

Comment: Is PHP installed as cgi or isapi module? Did you check the effective setting of display_startup... with var_dump(ini_get('display_startup_errors'), get_cfg_var('display_startup_errors')); ?

Comment: Have you tried to execute the script on the commandline? "php -f scriptname.php", or try to check the syntax with the "-l" flag.

Answer (score 18):

Setting error level in php file itself does not resolve the problem here because the file itself cannot be parsed !!

You need to change error_reporting line in your php.ini as follows:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

BTW: There are some examples in php.ini file about what to do to display which type of error messages.

Good luck,

mcemoz

Answer (score 5):

Apache doesn't always like to report parsing errors either.  From the command line, run

```
php -l <file>
```

The -l switch tells PHP to check file syntax.  See the man page.

Comment: That's some help, but all it tells you is that you do have parsing errors, but it give no indication as to where those errors might be!

Comment: To the most recent of my knowledge, the lint switch will report the nature and location of the first syntax error it finds within the given file.

Comment: I running php 5.3 on iis 6.0, and all -l does is say: "Errors parsing c:\path\file.php"

Comment: This is not about Apache.

Answer (score 2):

`E_STRICT` is not included in `E_ALL` (until PHP 6). If you want to keep getting `E_STRICT`

In php.ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

At runtime:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
```

You'll need to set the error reporting level (and [display_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)) in php.ini to see syntax errors. If PHP encounters a syntax error, the runtime doesn't get executed, so setting at runtime won't work. (See the `display_errors` link.)

Comment: In PHP 5.4.0, E_STRICT became part of E_ALL. See [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: I really don't recall if that was a valid argument to `error_reporting()` when I wrote this answer 6 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

You can verify the script syntax with this command in terminal:

```
php -l path/to/file.php
```

Personally, I added this line to my `~/.bash_profile` file so I can easily run `php -l` on all files in the current working directory:

```
phpl() { for i in *.php; do php -l $i; done }
```

If you're really hardcore, you can even run your app from the command line. You'll have a much better chance of seeing compile-time errors, and it's just kinda cool.

You can use the $argv variable to get the first argument, $argv[1], then use that as the request.

```
<?php
// show those errors!
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// simulate a web server request
$request = '/' . isset($argv[1]) ? ltrim($argv[1], '/') : '/';
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $request;
```

Then you can run your script via command line. This would be the equivalent of visiting: 
*your-webapp.com/request/uri/here*

```
php /path/to/script.php request/uri/here
```

Here is a more comprehensive example for running CodeIgniter via command line. It should work for many other frameworks too: http://phpstarter.net/2008/12/run-codeigniter-from-the-command-line-ssh/

Answer (score 1):

As Rasmus Lerdorf suggests, always use error_reporting(-1) on development server.

Comment: I can see that this was your first answer to a question, so you didn't have the rep to post this as a comment, but in the future, you might want to consider posting this as a comment. Answers are supposed to be a solution to the problem that you are pretty confident will solve the problem.

Comment: PHP Tip - error_reporting(-1) at the top of your script during dev to turn on all warnings, notices, etc in all versions of PHP
https://twitter.com/rasmus/status/7448448829

Answer (score 0):

Re: Blank screen of php death death, I discovered that setting

php_value error_reporting "E_ALL"   or
php_value error_reporting 8192

in .htaccess on my Windows 7, Wampserver w/ apache 2.2.4 and php 5.3.13  are  sure ways to get the blank php error screen -- today, June 3, 2014. These htaccess lines DO set the desires value in phpinfo(), but the display of the errors happens only when the line is commented out (not used) in htaccess.

BUT... the next minute I discover that

php_value error_reporting 8191

DOES set the phpinfo() value AND also allows display of  the error messages to the browser!    D'oh! It must be an integer and also apparently a particular or valid integer, and not just a large enough integer!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Zend Framework (v1) and you're using the Autoloader, the following code will prevent parse errors from being displayed:

`self::$Autoloader->suppressNotFoundWarnings(true);`

See the following answer for more details:

[Display php errors when using Zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201709/display-php-errors-when-using-zend-framework#1201752)

Comment: Was ZF mentioned in the original post?

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: @VolkerK - That's the thing. Could it be IIS-specific problem?