# Zend framework not showing errors

Tags: zend-framework

I read via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201709/disply-php-errors-when-using-zend-framework) how to turn on error reporting in Zend Framework but WHERE exactly do you put these statements? I've tried in public/index.php, in the file I'm working in, initializer.php but nothing prints out errors, always just a blank screen.

It's beyond me why a framework would come with a setting like this by default. Anyone know how I can see my php errors?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code in the beginning of your script which is executed when URL is called.

If the url is www.example.com, put the lines at the beginning of index.php.
If it's www.example.com/news.php, put it in news.php

This is actually not a question of Zend Framework, rather your php.ini settings.
Check out this [php.ini settings](http://sk2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

Comment: I'm aware of the php.ini settings but afaik Zend overrides those too.

Answer (score 0):

To show errors in zend framework

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```