# PHP swallowing exception

Tags: php

I'm trying to debug a PHP script that fails silently.

I've found where an exception is thrown, but the process exits before it can be caught.

The two try-catch blocks have been added by me. The surrounding code comes from Magento.

```
class Varien_Image {
    function __construct($fileName=null, $adapter=Varien_Image_Adapter::ADAPTER_GD2)
    {
        try {
            $this->_getAdapter($adapter);
            $this->_fileName = $fileName;
            if (isset($fileName)) {
                $this->open(); // throws here from a few frames deeper
            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "WE DO GET HERE\n";
            throw $e;
        }
    }
    //...
}

class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image ... {
    //...
    public function getImageProcessor() {
        //...
        try {
            echo "START\n";
            $this->_processor = new Varien_Image($this->getBaseFile());
        } catch(Exception $e) {
           echo "BUT WE NEVER GET HERE - THE PROCESS EXITS INSTEAD\n";
        }
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

The output is

```
START
WE DO GET HERE
```

Why would the exception be swallowed or cause the process to die?

**Edit**

It exits with status code 255

Running through strace:

```
write(1, "WE DO GET HERE\n", 15WE DO GET HERE
)        = 15
write(3, "\1\0\0\0\1", 5)               = 5
shutdown(3, SHUT_RDWR)                  = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f254d9f3000, 151552)          = 0
close(2)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f254da1f000, 4096)            = 0
close(0)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f254da20000, 4096)            = 0
munmap(0x7f2548d95000, 266240)          = 0
munmap(0x7f2548d54000, 266240)          = 0
munmap(0x7f2548c91000, 266240)          = 0
brk(0x691f000)                          = 0x691f000
brk(0x679f000)                          = 0x679f000
brk(0x641e000)                          = 0x641e000
brk(0x5b9e000)                          = 0x5b9e000
brk(0x4f5e000)                          = 0x4f5e000
brk(0x4dde000)                          = 0x4dde000
brk(0x4c5e000)                          = 0x4c5e000
brk(0x4ade000)                          = 0x4ade000
brk(0x47de000)                          = 0x47de000
brk(0x465e000)                          = 0x465e000
brk(0x439e000)                          = 0x439e000
brk(0x3e9e000)                          = 0x3e9e000
brk(0x3813000)                          = 0x3813000
brk(0x3693000)                          = 0x3693000
brk(0x3513000)                          = 0x3513000
brk(0x3393000)                          = 0x3393000
munmap(0x7f2548c50000, 266240)          = 0
munmap(0x7f2548cd2000, 266240)          = 0
munmap(0x7f2548d13000, 266240)          = 0
munmap(0x7f2548dd6000, 266240)          = 0
munmap(0x7f2549e93000, 2126744)         = 0
munmap(0x7f2549c63000, 2293440)         = 0
munmap(0x7f2549a3a000, 2264288)         = 0
munmap(0x7f254a09b000, 2131176)         = 0
munmap(0x7f254a2a4000, 2247424)         = 0
munmap(0x7f254aa01000, 2151656)         = 0
munmap(0x7f254a4c9000, 5471824)         = 0
munmap(0x7f254ac0f000, 2164040)         = 0
munmap(0x7f254ae20000, 2209936)         = 0
munmap(0x7f254b03c000, 2267912)         = 0
brk(0x2c3a000)                          = 0x2c3a000
munmap(0x7f254d89e000, 1052672)         = 0
munmap(0x7f254d99f000, 266240)          = 0
munmap(0x7f254d84f000, 323584)          = 0
exit_group(255)                         = ?
+++ exited with 255 +++
```

It echo 'WE DO GET HERE', and then immediately starts to shutdown. The SHUTDOWN on fd 3 is socket to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing an unreported parser error, read this question for more information:
[Parse errors are not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941766/parse-errors-are-not-displayed)

But the basic answer is you need to add the following to your php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Also, your actual syntax error is on this line. You need the ending `;`

```
        echo "START\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think that's it. I do have the error_reporting setting as you have suggested. The missing semi-colon is a mistake made in writing the question. I'll fix the question.

Comment: Is there any chance there's a `die;` command somewhere in the `Varien_Image` logic?

Comment: Nope. Unless I'm missing something, the next line to run after throw should be the echo statement.

Comment: Yeah, but something inside the logic for that class could be calling exit() or die(). Maybe search for that code inside the folder and see if anything comes up.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar to this, though in a different context of PHP. On CentOS 6.7 PHP 5.3 there's a bug where cURLs to an https url will simply kill the program. No errors will be thrown, so you can try-catch until you're blue in the face and it will never give you a friendly error message.

(You can read about it here if your interested:
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=57970
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1249426)

I'm not suggesting that this has anything directly to do with your problem other than the fact that every now and again, a library -even a trusted one like cURL- will have a terrible run-time bug. I only found this after hugely verbose logging. I realize this question is a year old, but hopefully my tail of woe will be useful to someone else dealing with a "ninja" error like the kind you're describing.